# whenever app is background state we need call webservices is it possible

Tags: ios, background-process

Whenever myapp is background state we need call webservices. Is it possible?

I'm using this delegate methods but not calling. If anyone knows this requirements please let me know

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];

    return YES;
}

(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
    // We will add content here soon.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `NSURLSessionConfiguration` for Background

```
    -(NSURLSession *)backgroundSession 
{
static NSURLSession *backgroundSession = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"com.shinobicontrols.BackgroundDownload.BackgroundSession"];
    backgroundSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
});
return backgroundSession;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way,

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [self beginBackgroundUpdateTask];
     //Call the Web Services
        [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
    });



}



- (void) beginBackgroundUpdateTask
{
    self.backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
    }];
}

- (void) endBackgroundUpdateTask
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: self.backgroundTask];
    self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```